# Is possible to get random model in Google App Engine with some criteria or without?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to get some random model with some criteria added into query?

Is it possible without implementation of random index?

For example my query:

```
myChoice = DeleteMe.all().filter('gender', 'man').random()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Try this:

```
q = DeleteMe.all().filter('gender', 'man').run()
randModel = q.get(offset=random.ranint(0, q.count()-1))
```

This generates a random number between 0 and the number of elements returned by the query, and then fetches the result with that index.

Comment: Not sure but offset can be maximum 2000 and each seek cost 1 small i/o - limitation 2000 probably is removed not sure about seek cost?

Comment: @Chameleon: I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: using an offset will incur a charge (and time) for each skipped entity up to the offset, so isn't very efficient for large datasets

Comment: Looks that is good solution but better is to create random index to seek - it will cost more writes but much less reads.

Comment: @Chameleon: That's exactly what I'm doing... isn't it?

Comment: @Linuxios You can hit in one get without seek with random index - it is not the same.